# I can't add elements in my schema ($addToSet)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, mongoose-schema

I have such a scheme. When using the command, I want new items to be added there

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {                      //user id
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    books: [{                  //book that user uses    
            _id: {               //book id
                type: Number,
                required: true,
            },
            lessons: [{          //lessons of the book with progress
                type: String,
                required: true,
            }],
    }],
})
```

I am trying to add them this way.

```js
await userSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(author.id, { $addToSet: { books: {_id: bookid, lessons: progress} } })
```

`bookid` - is int value incremented by one.
`progress` - array of strings

But only an array of lessons is written to the base, without id.
When I add only the id, then not the id is added, but an array of lessons.
I've spent several hours already and I can't figure out why it doesn't want to add everything to the array. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `$push` operator:

```js
await userSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(author.id, {
  $push: { 
    books: {
      _id: bookid,
      lessons: progress
    }
  } 
})
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still inputs without id, only adds an array for some reason.

Comment: Try to `console.log(bookid)` before the query. Maybe it's null or undefined.